# How to use stage 1 babel plugin in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

[ESNext Proposal: The Pipeline Operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) is in *stage 1*.

*The Pipeline Operator* has an babel plugin: [babel-plugin-transform-pipeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-pipeline)

How to config `tsconfig.json` for using *stage 1 babel-plugin* in ts-node, webpack, rollup, karma, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you could chain typescript and babel compilation, but `Pipeline Operator` is not valid syntax for Typescript yet. There is github issue with feature proposition: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17718.